# Getting IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am making a program that takes screenshot of the screen. When I name the taken screenshot with simple name it worked perfectly. But when I named the taken screenshot using time.ctime() I got **IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument** error.

Python Code that worked fine:

```
import pyautogui

name = 'Screenshot.png'
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot.save(name)
```

Python Code that gave me **IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid error**:

```
import pyautogui
import time

name = time.ctime() + '.png'
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot.save(name)
```

**Python gave me this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
          pic.save(screenshot_name)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1932, in save
          fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Thu Jul 12 14:25:48 2018.png'
```

***What would be the solution for this problem?***

Comment: You cannot have `:` in your filenames on Windows (I think)

Comment: OMG it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: @AndrejKesely, in particular in the NTFS file system (required on the system drive), colon is used for named streams such as $DATA and $INDEX_ALLOCATION stream types. It's part of the fully-qualified stream name, not the base filename. Both files and directories can have named $DATA streams (e.g. "screenshot.png:streamname:$DATA"). Files also have a default, unnamed $DATA stream (e.g. "screenshot.png" is the same as "screenshot::$DATA"). Directories have a default index stream named "$I30" (e.g. "dirname" is the same as "dirname:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION").

Comment: "Thu Jul 12 14:25:48 2018.png" tries to create a file named "Thu Jul 12 14" with a stream named "25"  and "48 2018.png" as the type. The latter is not a valid stream type, so the file system returns `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID` to Windows, which sets the last Windows error to `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`, and in turn the C runtime sets `errno` to `EINVAL` (22).

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out.